# Roster and Time Mangement

Tags: excel, rostering

I'm fairly new to Excel, so I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for, however my query is this.

I am trying to create a roster for my workplace, I have created a drop down menu for Start Times in the first column and Work Hours Required for each day in the second column.  I can work out how to calculate a finish time in the third column, but if I leave the first column blank (ie: a day off) it calculates the third column as the sum of Column1 and Column2 (ie: "Blank Cell" + Work Hours = 7:30)

What I actually want displayed is "Blank Cell + Work Hours = Blank Cell

I'm sure its an =IF formula, but cant quite work it out [image: Spreadsheet Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in D2 and copy down the column as needed:

```
=IF(OR(B2="", C2=""), "", C2 + B2)
```

I included the "OR" part with two tests in case *either* of the input cells is blank.

Comment: Hey Vipkry,  Thanks for that.  Worked a charm :)